# Send User Password via Email with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am creating a android application where I'm using firebase auth but I don't want to send the confirmation email to user for confirming the user email address, instead I want to set a auto generated password for the user and send it to the users email so by that way I can verify his email.

Just wanted to know if it is possible or not, if yes then link to any guide or tutorial will be great.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome! This type of question will be viewed as overly broad, and will invite opinions rather than real answers. I think you would be better served by doing a web search to find resources that make sense for you. Thanks!

Comment: Are you emailing the plain text password to a user? or are you trying to verify the user's email?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. When user creates his account send a auto generated password on his email and also in realtime database or firestore create a field status corresponding to users Uid  and set default value to false. Also save that auto generated code in database. When user tries to login for the first time (check if status is false) then open a dialog and ask for the code send on email. if both code matches email verified change status to true else gives message incorrect code.

When the user login for the first time ask his email and password. Then verify it in auth module. If user exists then retrieve his data from realtime database and check if value of status is false or true. If value is false this means he is logging for the first time. So, open either a activity or a dialog which asks his code send on email. Then check if both code matches. If yes then this is the correct user. Send him to home activity and set the value of status to true in database.

Comment: Did you clearly understand what to do @Rajnish Kumar ??

Comment: thanks for the answer, if you explain the first login part little more in details I will be very thankful.