# Firebase - Send Password via Email after User Account Creation

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on a college app in which only the administrator has the right to create user accounts. On successful User Account creation, the user gets an email with his user email and password as plain text.

I am already familiar with the email verification and password reset mail in firebase but I am not allowed to do that.

I already looked at answer to this question: [Send User Password via Email with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51051655/send-user-password-via-email-with-firebase) but it is very less helpful as the answer provided is complicated to understand.

So all I want is the password to be sent via email whenever a user is created.

PS: I am working with Web Interface (JavaScript). How do I do that? It would be even nice if I get help with some code chunks included.

Comment: You're going to have to arrange for that to happen on your backend.  Firebase Authentication doesn't do what you're describing.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the reply. BTW do you have any ideas how can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using firebase cloud functions following the steps below

1. Setup Admin SDK following the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup
2. Add a Firebase Authentication Listener https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events
3. You can send mail with sendgrid [See this article](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/sendgrid)

If you want to really get familiar with cloud functions you can start [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)